# Generate SHA1 HMAC with UTF-8 input on JavaScript (not Node.js)

Tags: javascript, utf-8, hmac, cryptojs, hmacsha1

With that lib : 
http://locutus.io/php/misc/pack/
Bufferize secret for hmac:

```
var packedSecr = pack('H*', $secret);
```

Than pack time:

```
var packedTime = pack('NN', 0, Math.floor((time() + $time_offset) / 30));
```

both strings has UTF-8 characters and fully coincide with PHPs packed.
Than I need create hash_hmac and here has a troubles:

```
function hash_hmac(str,key){
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(str, key);
    var resInUTF8 = convertWordArrayToUint8Array(hash);
    var string = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(resInUTF8);
    console.log(hash.toString());
    /* 5cdc66cb8cf2a08b78f149502e05b9538c7a72a9*/
    console.log(string);
    /* \�fˌ�x�IP.�S�zr� */
    return string;
}
```

But PHP make defferent hmac:

```
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha1', $packedTime, $bufferedSecret, true);
echo $hmac;
/* v��j��q����V��� */
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha1', $packedTime, $bufferedSecret, false);
echo $hmac;
/* 17761ff6f06ad0db71f0a588fcf002d756c1d1eb */
```

For convert WordArray used that mini lib:
https://gist.github.com/getify/7325764

If I just create hmac with "A-z" and "0-9" symbols all is coincide.
PHP:

```
$string = "aBc059";
$secret = "Tcs437";
echo hash_hmac('sha1', $string, $secret, false); 
/* 00012176b13b26f8fdb9f8dfcaf553e9aa0401ac */
echo hash_hmac('sha1', $string, $secret, true);
/* !v�;&�������S�� */
```

JS:

```
var string = "aBc059";
var secret = "Tcs437";

hash_hmac(string,secret)

function hash_hmac(str,key){
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(str, key);
    var resInUTF8 = convertWordArrayToUint8Array(hash);
    var string = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(resInUTF8);
    console.log(hash.toString());
    /* 00012176b13b26f8fdb9f8dfcaf553e9aa0401ac */
    console.log(string);
    /* !v�;&�������S�� */
    return string;
}
```